# Autopilot and Functions collecting data he

Tags: node.js, function, post, twilio, voice

I have a task in autopilot that collects data from a caller then calls a function using a redirect.
I cant seem to access the post variables. please assist.

so when run this I get the following error

Error - 82002

Error on Twilio Function response

produced by this line of code

*var first_name = memory.twilio.collected_data.lead_qual.lead_qual_first;*

remove that line and it works fine just no access to the collected data.

following are the dependencies I have included, the task code and the function.

### looks like this..
Dependencies......>

lodash 4.17.11
twilio 3.29.2
fs 0.0.1-security
got 9.6.0
moment-timezone 0.5.14
moment 2.29.1
xmldom 0.1.27
twilio/runtime-handler 1.0.1
util 0.11.0
request 2.87.0

### Task......>

```
    {
"actions": [
{
"collect": {
"name": "lead_qual",
"questions": [
{
"question": "What is your first name?",
"name": "lead_qual_first",
"type": "Twilio.FIRST_NAME"
},
{
"question": "What is your last name?",
"name": "lead_qual_last",
"type": "Twilio.LAST_NAME"
},
{
"question": "If we are disconnected what is the best phone number to reach you on??",
"name": "lead_qual_phone",
"type": "Twilio.PHONE_NUMBER"
},
{
"question": "What is your date of birth?",
"name": "lead_qual_dob",
"type": "Twilio.DATE"
},
{
"question": "Are you currently covered by disability, yes or no?",
"name": "lead_qual_disability",
"type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
},
{
"question": "Do you have any form of federal medicare, yes or no?",
"name": "lead_qual_medicare",
"type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
},
{
"question": "Do you have medicaid or another state sponsored insurance, yes or no?",
"name": "lead_qual_medicaid",
"type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
},
{
"question": "Finally, Are you currently insured, yes or no?",
"name": "lead_qual_insured",
"type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
}
],
"on_complete": {
"redirect": {
"method": "POST",
"uri": "https://health-agent-3097.twil.io/Evaluate-Answers"
}
}
}
}
]
}
```

### Function ......>

```
// This is your new function. To start, set the name and path on the left.

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

// Require the component used to post.

const got = require("got");

// Time zone for EST to check times with.

let moment = require('moment-timezone');

const now = moment().tz('America/New_York');

// initialize the return object

var responseObject = {};

var first_name = memory.twilio.collected_data.lead_qual.lead_qual_first;

responseObject =

{

"actions":[

  {

    "say":"Force Override result"

  },

  {

    "redirect": {

      "method": "POST",

      "uri": "task://goodbye"

    }

  }

]
}

// This callback is what is returned in response to this function being invoked.

callback(null, responseObject);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`memory` is not one of the arguments passed to a Twilio Function. You are passed `event`, `context` and `callback`. You are using the `callback` correctly and the `context` includes your environment variables.

The `event` object is what you need here though. The `event` includes all the parameters sent to the Function. According to [the documentation on the Autopilot request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request) you will be sent a `Memory` parameter. That `Memory` will be a JSON string that needs parsing. So instead, try accessing:

```
const memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
const firstName = memory.twilio.collected_data.lead_qual.lead_qual_first;
```

Let me know how you get on with that.

Comment: I did try that initially and I am getting null values there... also 5 days ago the developer support sent me the following...

can you please use memory.twilio.collected_data instead of twilio.collected_data
and event.Memory​. This collected data is the post request under Memory > "twilio" > "collected_data":https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request

apparently the memory variable is supposed to be passed in the POST not as a parameter of the function. However I have not been able to get a response from them since as to this issue.

Comment: Does the project being in development mode change how this works somehow?

Comment: It shouldn't change that it is in development mode, no. Have you tried examining the entire event object to see if you can find the parameters you are looking for>?

Comment: Ok so after much debugging  and review this is the magic line of missing code...

const memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);

It appears the Memory object is passed in as JSON String and must be parsed to access the node members.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Ah, apologies, since answering this question I have also gone through this myself and realised you needed to parse. I will update the answer to make that clear.